# Assign associative array value only if empty in bash

Tags: bash

Have associative array

```
OPTIONS[a]="a-value"
```

have another array `id` and need set a value from OPTIONS only when some value is NOT set, so something like

```
id[KEY1]=${id[KEY1]:-OPTIONS[a]}
```

but this not works.

How to use the bash's `:-` "variable substitution" with associative arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close. This works for me:

```
$ OPTIONS[a]="a-value"
$ id[KEY1]="b"
$ id[KEY1]=${id[KEY1]:-${OPTIONS[a]}}
$ echo ${id[KEY1]}
b
$ unset id
$ id[KEY1]=${id[KEY1]:-${OPTIONS[a]}}
$ echo ${id[KEY1]}
a-value
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Why is it _now_ obvious? :) :)